# Launch background process from sh and close the terminal

Tags: shell-script, background-process

How can this be achieved in sh (not bash!)?

```
nohup sh -c 'helper-bcpy.sh "$0" "$1" "$2" "$3"' "$num" "$full_path" "$log" "$log_finished" >/dev/null &
```

I would have expected it to send the process in background (which it does) and detach it from the terminal (which it doesn't do — if I close the terminal from where I launched the script, `helper-bcpy.sh` won't fully execute although it seems the time-consuming wget call gets executed correctly...).

I know I could use `disown` but I need to do this in sh not bash...

```
#!/bin/sh

# $num $full_path $log $log_finished - computed before from parameters received by the script

nvram set led_disable=1
service restart_leds >/dev/null

nohup sh -c 'helper-bcpy.sh "$0" "$1" "$2" "$3"' "$num" "$full_path" "$log" "$log_finished" >/dev/null &

echo "copy process launched..."
exit 0
```

`helper-bcpy.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

wget -m -np -nH -nv --cut-dirs="$1" "$2" 1>/dev/null 2>"$3"
nvram set led_disable=0
service restart_leds
mv "$3" "$4"

exit 0
```

I need to make this work on an Asus router that uses the Merlin firmware

Comment: What is your `/bin/sh` symlinked to ? Which OS ? Do `ls -l /bin/sh` . You likely want to use something other, like `screen` to launch it in background.

Comment: Have you tried running the calling script with `nohup`, instead of using `nohup` in that script?

Comment: @Serg: sh is symlinked to BusyBox and the system is reported by uname as follows: Linux AC66U 2.6.22.19 #1 Fri Feb 3 00:20:05 EST 2017 mips ASUSWRT-Merlin. I followed your advice and installed screen and I can accomplish my goal this way.

Comment: @TimKennedy: I also tried what you suggested but obtained the same effect as before: process gets backgrounded but remains attached to the terminal (if I closed it, the script stops). My problem is solved but I'm still wondering why my original solution did not work, as I read that it should have accomplished exactly what I wanted. Thank you both for your suggestions!

Comment: I just noticed that in your `nohup` you are redirecting `stdout`, but not `stderr`.   You need to do something like `nohup ...[snip] > /dev/null 2>&1`

That `2>&1` is what will disconnect STDERR from your process and redirect it to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Why is the `sh -c` needed? Can't you just execute your script as is?

Comment: @tim-kennedy, redirecting stdout and/or stderr is optional, not required. By default they will go to nohup.out

Comment: @tim-kennedy: I redirected like that because I wanted the statistics about the transfer

Comment: @bsd,  I thought that the parameters were not passed correctly without -c

Comment: What happens if you just run `nohup ./helper-bcpy.sh "$num" "$full_path" "$log" "$log_finished" >/dev/null &`

Comment: @bsd: it works as described in the initial post: it sends the process in background but it doesn't disconnect it from the terminal, so it was unnecessary to use the -c switch.

Comment: I know no details of the ASUS router's shell. Have you run other commands that disconnected successfully? That would be the first thing I would do to see if its the router's shell implementation or your script/invocation